# (Pytest-Xdist) ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'execnet.rsync'

Tags: python, pytest, pyinstaller, pytest-xdist

I have been trying to bundle my tests written on `pytest` as `.exe` file.

I have tried the code mentioned in the pytest documentation for including the third party plugins:
https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/example/simple.html#freezing-pytest

My code is as follows:

```
import pytest
import xdist
import pytest_rerunfailures

if len(sys.argv) > 1 and sys.argv[1] == "--pytest":
    sys.exit(pytest.main(sys.argv[2:], plugins=[xdist, pytest_rerunfailures]))
```

Interestingly, the code works for pytest_rerunfailures but when I run the .exe using `-n 2`, it shows the following error:

```
ERROR: usage: mainfile [options] [file_or_dir] [file_or_dir] [...]
mainfile: error: unrecognized arguments: -n
  inifile: None
  rootdir: A:\New folder (2)\Scripted\dist
```

Here `mainfile` is the name of the `exe` file.

Also, it would be worth mentioning that `xdist` command-line options work when the tests are run normally but when bundled as `exe`, the create this issue.

`ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'execnet.rsync'`

Could someone help me out here?